# Zero-sum game with different payoff matrix?

Tags: game-theory

In zero-sum games, can we consider a situation where the players have different information (say asymmetric information)? This will result in a different payoff matrix for each player (with different entries) which means, the Nash Equilibrium would be different from each player's perspective. I do not know how to discuss the Nash equilibrium of the game? should I simply say there is two NE (for a two-person game) and that's all? Or I can find a unique NE that both players with different payoff matrices agree on that?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What is exactly the question though?

Comment: The question is how should I find the NE (I updated the question). For example, in a two-person game, there will be two payoff matrices, one from the row player's perspective and the other one from the column player's perspective. Thus, there will be two NE from each player's perspective.

Comment: You should give a concrete example.It really depends on the model. Here is one example of such a situation: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6465362.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I will go through this document. But isn't it for repeated games?

Comment: True. This is just an example of a similar situation. As I said, you need to precisely state the model and assumptions about the game.